# Connect from one server to another via SSH, Iptable rules needed

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I have 2 servers and want to be able to connect via SSH from server A to B and vice versa. What Iptables rules should I set on both machines to make this possible ?
SSH is runnning on default port 22

Comment: possible duplicate of [iptables Ubuntu VPS SSH rule](http://serverfault.com/questions/313073/iptables-ubuntu-vps-ssh-rule)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the next rule to both hosts. You can define source and destination ip address (-d) in case you only want to connect from this hosts in a bilateral connection. In any case you should take a look to the iptables documentation

**iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp  --dport 22 --m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED  -j ACCEPT**